# Why was my answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

Out of interest, why was my answer to [Why does Intel Graphics Installer depend on ttf-ancient-fonts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466503/why-does-intel-graphics-installer-depend-on-ttf-ancient-fonts) deleted (without comment)?

Answer (score 5):

I took a look at the question and your answer.

At a glance, the answer you gave doesn't appear to have anything to do with the question asked.

It was flagged as such and deleted by a moderator as result.

The OP asked about why an installer depends on a certain font package. The answer provided by yourself is a one liner - which is difficult to parse and understand in relation to the question.

I can only assume that this is why it was flagged.

Perhaps you should elaborate more in your answers? Show how they are relevant to the question (posting a Unicode character that probably a number of people can't see and only see a square or whatever the browser decides to display when the font doesn't have a glyph for it is not particularly helpful).

Additionally, you used "we" in your answer - who is "we"? How are you a representative of this "we" and why is your answer authoritative in that sense? Makes it difficult to see the relationship between yourself, the answer and the question as asked.

Comment: Perhaps commenting asking for the very things you point out would have made the answer better would have been a better response than deleting without comment when a new user registers specifically to answer a question? (I know it wasn't you who closed it.)

Comment: @unixsmurf - I can't really speak for the mod who did delete the answer (or for the user the flagged it without commenting).

Comment: @unixsmurf You're right in the sense that a comment should have been added, but [fledermaus](http://askubuntu.com/users/438992/fledermaus) should have explained that in the answer, so we can have a better understanding of it, and avoid any issues..  The answer was somehow vague, and didn't make sence at firt glance :)